# Expanding to second order

Tags: probability-distributions, taylor-expansion, characteristic-functions

I have the following characteristic function of S.

[image: Characteristic function of S]

I understood how I got to this characteristic function yet the next part I want to show that as $$ n \rightarrow \infty, \varphi_S (t) \rightarrow e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} $$

The solution states:

[image]

I am very confused how to get to even the first line. I feel like it's something to do with Taylor series yet I am unsure.

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I know, I'm sorry. Was in a bit of a rush. Will convert to text when I get the time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $n$ is large, the arguments of the exponentials are small, allowing a limited Taylor development, and

$$pe^{ka}+(1-p)e^{-{a/k}}\approx p\left(1+ka+\frac{k^2a^2}2\right)+(1-p)\left(1-\frac ak+\frac{a^2}{2k^2}\right).$$

The constant term is $1$. The linear coefficient is

$$\frac{pk^2-(1-p)}ka=0.$$

Then the quadratic coefficient (which I let you evaluate exactly) will be proportional to $a^2$, and of the form $\dfrac{bt^2}n$. Finally, by a well-known formula,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{bt^2}{n}\right)^n=e^{bt^2}.$$

Higher order terms in the development will decrease faster and bring no contribution to the limit.